# How to change fancyBox 2 options at runtime?

Tags: jquery, resize, fancybox-2

I am using fancyBox 2.1.5 and when initializing I use:

```
$("selector").fancybox({
    'width'    : '95%',
    'height'   : '95%',
    'autoSize' : false,
    'margin'   : '20', //this is default, i don't set it explicitly
    ...
});
```

When a user resizes the browser to a smaller size I would like to resize the fancyBox as well in order to fill up the whole browser viewport: `'width': '100%', 'height': '100%', 'margin': '0'` at runtime. Is this possible?

Comment: have you try with @media queries?

Comment: Upon start fancyBox calculate the absolute width and height in px and recalculate them when the browser is resized. With @media queries I can't access fancyBox initial options.

Comment: Also check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.13 if that helps

Comment: 10x, I was able to achieve Supersized effect with 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%', 'margin': '0' but I want to apply it only when the browser height is resized bellow let's say 700px otherwise  to be 'width': '95%', 'height': '95%', 'margin': '20'. It seems that fancyBox doesn't support options change at runtime.